# Pushing Sound files to an Array with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an Iphone keyboard extension that I am working on and the keyboard plays sounds when a character is clicked. I would like to randomize the sounds for my buttonPresssed function. So far I am only able to have one sound for that function and was able to get the spacePressed function to play another. Essentialy I would like the buttonPressed function to play random sounds from an array. Thank you in advanced...

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    var keyboardView: UIView!

    //sounds
    var sound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound1", ofType: "mp3")!)

    var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound2", ofType: "mp3")!)

    var sound3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound3", ofType: "mp3")!)


    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadInterface()

        //prepare sounds
        //audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    }

    func loadInterface(){

        let keyboardNib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)

        self.keyboardView = keyboardNib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        view.addSubview(self.keyboardView)

        view.backgroundColor = self.keyboardView.backgroundColor

        self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: "advanceToNextInputMode", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    }

    @IBAction func buttonPressed (sender: UIButton){
       let title = sender.titleForState(.Normal)

       let proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

       proxy.insertText(title!)
       audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound2)

        //play sound
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    @IBAction func spacePressed (sender: UIButton){
        let proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

        proxy.insertText(" ")

        audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound3)
        audioPlayer.play()

    }

    @IBAction func deletePressed (sender: UIButton){

        let proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

        proxy.deleteBackward()

    }

    @IBAction func capsLockPressed (sender: UIButton){


    }

    @IBAction func returnKeyPressed (sender: UIButton){


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    }

    override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
        // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
    }

    override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput?) {
        // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.


    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754957/pick-a-random-ui-image-view-swift-2/33758098#33758098 How to randomize array index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend adding the sounds to an `array` like so:

```
var sound1 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound1", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound2", ofType: "mp3")!)
var sound3 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sound3", ofType: "mp3")!)

var soundArray : [NSURL] = [sound1, sound2, sound3]
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Then create a random sound generator:

```
func playRandomSound() {
    let randNo = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(soundArray!.count))) // 0...ArrayCount

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundArray![randNo])
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i try to add that array below the sounds i am getting "instance member "sound1" cannot be used on type keyboardviewcontroller"  Thoughts? I was trying something similiar to this but keep getting that instance member message error.

Comment: You may have to do some further research into if you can play additional sounds on keyboard press. The OS already has a click sound so it might not be possible without making a custom keyboard.

Comment: I can play sounds through my custom keyboard. Just trying to figure out how to randomize the sound played on  buttonPressed function which represents the "a-z" keys ... So right now when i press a-z i get my sound and when i press the space key i get another sound. Just want the a-z key to play from an array list so its not always the same sound. Sorry if i wasnt clear. I guess i could try making a view for q-p, a-l, and z-m and assign a different sound to each of those actions.

Comment: I will test again when I get at my desk again to make sure I haven't made a mistake, but the above code should give you what you want to randomize the array. Give me 20 mins!

Comment: One thing I ran into while playing sounds in rapid succession was latency when creating the sounds each time. Rather than store the URL in the array, store an `AVAudioPlayer` for each URL in the array, then just pull that `AVAudioPlayer` out of the array and play it.

Comment: This would happen if you are playing large files, but for keyboard taps I am guessing these are very small, @antoneking??

Comment: @zappiDev Actually, I had it happen with just playing a beep sound.

Comment: No problem, I was limited without a computer! Glad to be of assistance.